# AS3: limit objects to stage width?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I want to limit the creation of objects acording to the stage width.

My method is the following:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<7; i++){
```

If I put something like this, it won't work

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.width); i++){
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Full code:**

```
    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D(this);  
sim.createStageWalls();  
// make a heavy circle  
sim.addCircle({x:3, y:3, radius:0.4, density:1});  
// create a few platforms  

// make 26 dominoes  
for (var i:int = 0; i<7; i++){  
//End
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:18, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:17, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

//Mid end

      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});

}  
sim.start();  
sim.mouseDrag();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you want to use is `stage.stageWidth`.

**Update:** If your code throws an error, it could be that `stage` is not available **or** not *yet* available. In Flash CS5, the stage property should always be available. In "pure" Actionscript or Flex projects (using Flex Builder or FlashDevelop), you should make sure that your class inherits from a flash class that has the `stage` property and you'll also have to wait for `stage` to be available.
A save way to make sure `stage` is available, is listening to the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event. Eg. something like this:

```
public function Constructor()
{
    super();
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onInit)
}

private function onInit(evt:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(evt.type, onInit);

    // stage should be accessible here. Initialize your code here!
}
```