# AS3: StageWidth for BOX2D?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I know BOX2D uses meters, and AS3 uses pixels.

I'm trying to create objects which are limited to the stageWidth.

If I do this variable:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth); i++){...}
```

The animation will freeze, and this output appears:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Box2D.Collision::b2BroadPhase/CreateProxy()
at Box2D.Collision.Shapes::b2Shape/CreateProxy()
at Box2D.Dynamics::b2Body/CreateShape()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox.objects::CircleObject/build()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox::QuickObject/init()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox::QuickObject()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox.objects::CircleObject()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox::QuickBox2D/create()
at com.actionsnippet.qbox::QuickBox2D/addCircle()
at BOX2D_Test_Tutorial_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Full Code:

```
    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D(this);  
sim.createStageWalls();  
// make a heavy circle  
sim.addCircle({x:3, y:3, radius:0.4, density:1});  
// create a few platforms  

// make pins 
for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth); i++){  
//End
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:18, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:17, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

//Mid end

      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});

}  
sim.start();  
sim.mouseDrag();
```

Comment: You asked this twice on purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3: limit objects to stage width?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20292/as3-limit-objects-to-stage-width)

Comment: I updated my answer in the other question. I think your problem is because you're accessing `stage` at a point of time where it's not initialized, eg. `null`. Therefore you get this error.

Comment: I had a look at your flash file. The issue isn't the `stage`. That works fine. I don't know exactly what the problem is, because the error occurs during the creation of the objects. It could be, because you're adding a *huge* amount of objects. The stageWidth is 350 and you're creating 350 * 9 objects in that loop. Most of these objects will be *outside* your physics world, because the stage is in pixels, while your physics-world has another unit (meters). That's probably causing the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are surpassing the limit of bodies in Box2D, at 3150 circles I can't imagine why you would need so many, is there a logic error or will you divide this number by something?

Edit:

If you want to evenly space objects across the stage you can do this:

```
var meterWidth = stage.stageWidth/meter;// meter can be 30 or whatever your scale is

// Adds the distance between each object to i on each iteration and stops at the width
for (var i = 0; i < meterWidth; i += meterWidth/numberOfObjects)
{
    sim.addCircle({x:i, y:18, radius:0.1, density:0});// i is the x coordinate
}
```

Edit:

For anyone interested, the maximum body count in Box2D can be changed in b2Settings.

Comment: Is on the main timeline, the first frame to be precise.

Comment: I just looked at your error and it seems the problem is inside the loop, do you know if it is the stage that you can't access?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the project: http://gabrielmeono.com/download/BOX2D.zip

Comment: Your problem is not the stage becuase I can assign a variable to stagewidth

Comment: I edited my answer now that I know what's wrong

Comment: So you figured it out after you read my comment? Nice job Sherlock :)

Comment: Actually I figured it out when I downloaded his code, but you can take the credit if you want. :)